# Removing and replacing arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Basically, I am given an array of numbers and I have to count all the negative numbers.
Then make a new array that contains all of the positive numbers from the previous with the length of the array being firstarray-numberOfNegatives

Here is my code:

```
public void removeNegatives()
  {

      int numberOfNegative = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length-1; i++)
      {
            if (numbers[i] < 0) numberOfNegative++;
      }
      int [] numbers2 = new int[numbers.length-numberOfNegative];
      int count = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < numbers2.length; i++)
      {
          if (numbers[count] > 0) numbers2[i] = numbers[count];
          count++;
          System.out.println(numbers2[i]);
      }
      numbers = numbers2;
  }
```

I am getting the wrong result: negative numbers are replaced with 0s

Comment: Take a look at java enhanced `for` loop i.e. `for num in numbers`, for example @ http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/the-enhanced-for-loop.html

Answer (score 1):

At first write `i < numbers.length;` or `i <= numbers.length-1;` instead of `i < numbers.length-1;`
And then fix code.
Also note that you can have zeros in your 'numbers' array, so in if() in first for() you should write <=0 instead of <0

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
  {
      if (numbers[i] > 0) numbers2[count] = numbers[i];
      count++;
      System.out.println(numbers2[count-1]);
  }
```

Comment: Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
 at BunchOfArrayMethods.removeNegatives(BunchOfArrayMethods.java:77)

Comment: I can's say where is the problem.I even don't have your final code.Debug, it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: you have an off-by-one error in your first for loop. Walk through some small example arrays in your head or on paper and you'll see.

Secondly: I think you are using your two index counters backwards in the second section. The `count` is supposed to be used in  your new array, and `i` in your old one.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public void removeNegatives()
  {

      int numberOfNegative = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) // 
      {
            if (numbers[i] < 0) numberOfNegative++;
      }
      int [] numbers2 = new int[numbers.length-numberOfNegative];
      int count = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
      {
          if (numbers[i] >= 0) numbers2[count++] = numbers[i]; //
      }
      numbers = numbers2;
  }
```

Comment: Note second test should be: `if (numbers[i] >= 0)` (better for comprehension)

Answer (score 0):

Need to **reverse your index variables** in the second pass. Also the first loop had a **length-1 instead of length**. The **second loop should go over the full length** of the original array not the resulting array.

```
public void removeNegatives()
{
  int numberOfNegative = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    if (numbers[i] < 0)
      numberOfNegative++;
  int [] numbers2 = new int[numbers.length-numberOfNegative];
  int count = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
  {
      if (numbers[i] >= 0) {
          numbers2[count] = numbers[i];
          System.out.println(numbers2[count]);
          count++;
      }
  }
  numbers = numbers2;
}
```

Comment: I corrected it. The println needed to come before the count++ and all of it was dependent on the number being non-negative

Answer (score 0):

Run through a debugger and watch this line...
That -1 is suspicious

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length-1; i++)
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

In

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers2.length; i++)
  {
      if (numbers[count] > 0) numbers2[i] = numbers[count];
      count++;
      System.out.println(numbers2[i]);
  }
  numbers = numbers2;
```

}

You are iterating as many times as numbers2 has positions, however, you increase i at every pass (in the for loop) regardless of whether you fund a positive number or not. Your output arrray would therefore have the first numbers2.length positive integers of numbers interleaved with a bunch of 0s!